Growing list of lists in for loop
I want to list all the preimages of the critical values of a polynomial, and I'd like to have them in a list of lists so that all preimages of the same critical values are in the same list.
p[z_] = z^5+z^3+2z;
cpt = z/.Solve[p'[z]==0,z];  (*critical points*)
cvl = p[cpt];  (*critical values*)
s={{}};
For[i=0, i <= Length[cvl],i++,
s = Append[s, z/.Solve[p[z]==Extract[cvl,{i}],z]]
]
s

I've tried tweaking it but there always seems to be a problem with appending to s. I tried joining too, that doesn't solve the issue. If I try to print s in the for loop, I get some "Null", and I am not sure why...
Thank you in advance!

You are defining a function incorrectly.  See documentation.

List indexes start with 1, not 0, in MMA. And try s=Table[z/.Solve[p[z]==Extract[cvl,{i}],z],{i,1,Length[cvl]}] to see if that gives the result that you want.

Thanks, that solved the problem!

better to use Sow and Reap than Append and AppendTo to build a list on the fly

I typically find code with Sow and Reap quite difficult to understand. Instead, you can use an Association. It might be even faster than Sow and Reap.

Simpler to use functional programming structures like Map.
(1) Get the critical values.
p[z_] = z^5 + z^3 + 2 z;
critvals = RootReduce[Map[p, SolveValues[p'[z] == 0, z]]];

(2) Map a function that solves p[z]==val for each val in critvals.
solsets = Map[SolveValues[p[z] == #, z] &, critvals];

These are not so pretty.
In[422]:= solsets[[1, 1]] // InputForm
(* Out[422]//InputForm=
Root[{6272 + 6308*#1^2 + 3125*#1^4 & ,
    -#1 + 2*#2 + #2^3 + #2^5 & }, {2, 1}] *)

(4) Numerically they are not bad of course (albeit they are complex-valued).
In[420]:= N[solsets]

(* Out[420]= {{-0.69217 - 1.1052 I, -0.40771 + 0.682809 I, -0.40771 + 
   0.682809 I, 0.747451 + 0.807933 I, 
  0.76014 - 1.06835 I}, {-0.76014 + 1.06835 I, -0.747451 - 0.807933 I,
   0.40771 - 0.682809 I, 0.40771 - 0.682809 I, 
  0.69217 + 1.1052 I}, {-0.69217 + 1.1052 I, -0.40771 - 
   0.682809 I, -0.40771 - 0.682809 I, 0.747451 - 0.807933 I, 
  0.76014 + 1.06835 I}, {-0.76014 - 1.06835 I, -0.747451 + 0.807933 I,
   0.40771 + 0.682809 I, 0.40771 + 0.682809 I, 0.69217 - 1.1052 I}} *)

